# Using data from another class

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a class in which I query to a DB some informations and I would to use these informations to display.

*Class where I would to show data.*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FindUser from './FindUser';
let findUser = new FindUser();

class ShowProfile extends Component{
construct(props) {
super(props);
}
//...

render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.container}>
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
          <View style={style.page}>
            <Text style={visualProfilo.text}>Name:</Text>
            <Text style={visualProfilo.text1}>{this.state.FirstName}</Text>
            <Text style={visualProfilo.text}>Surname:</Text>
            <Text style={visualProfilo.text1}>{this.state.LastName}</Text>
//...
}
```

*Class where I query the DB*

```
class FindUser extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    findUser(cf) {
        let params = {};
        params = {
          "Person.FiscalCode": cf
        };
        //... query to DB
          .then(response => {
            let utente = response.docs[0];
            console.log("name: ", user.Person.FirstName)
```

In this way I log the FirstName, than I would to use these informations to display as `this.state.FirstName` in `ShowProfile`. How can I do?

Comment: Use react native async storage https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

Comment: You can use React Context for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very best approach to achieve what you is using React Native async storage, you save user information in it and retrieve into state using componentDidMount lifecycle method.

Here is an example

You may fetch user information from class A using this

```
   import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

   GetUser = () => {
        return fetch( "http://sample.com/api/user/user.php", {
          method: "POST",
          headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            action: 'fetch'
          })
        }).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJsonFromServer) => {
             AsyncStorage.setItem("datakey", JSON.stringify(responseJsonFromServer));
        })
      }
```

And in class B , you use the **componentDidMount** to retrieve the information from async-storage using the key declared for your data and save them in state as done below

```
this.state = {
        FirstName: "",
        OtherData: ""
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        AsyncStorage.getItem("datakey").then((data) =>{
          const val = JSON.parse(data);
          this.setState({
            FirstName: data.firstname,
            OtherData: data.otherdata,
          })
        })
      }
```

You may now display the data in your **render function** like this

```
View>
  <Text>{this.state.Firstname}</Text>
  <Text>{this.state.OtherData}</Text>
</View>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Ok and then I can use the values in this.setState where I want?

Comment: Answer Updated. Don't forget to mark as answer if this helps you

Comment: I have tried your code, but I receive this error: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of null. Maybe because I don't do a fetch but I recover data from: `global.user.db
      .localdb()
      .find({
        selector: params
      })`

Comment: What response type does your API returns? And also the answer is a guide to achieving what you need. Does your API data contains `FirstName` ?

Comment: Yes It contains FirstName, I get the information through: `global.user.data` then with `global.user.data.Person.FirstName` I recover the firstname.

If I console.log the `response` from your code, it doesn't been print.

Comment: I have understand the problem! The view in the ShowProfile page load first the data, for this reason the FirstName is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Use **global variable** like that

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
    import FindUser from './FindUser';
    let findUser = new FindUser();

    class ShowProfile extends Component{
    construct(props) {
    super(props);
    global.Fusername=""; 
    global.Lusername=""; 
    }
    //...

    render() {
        return (
          <View style={style.container}>
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
              <View style={style.page}>
                <Text style={visualProfilo.text}>Name:</Text>
                <Text style={visualProfilo.text1}>{global.username}</Text>
                <Text style={visualProfilo.text}>Surname:</Text>
                <Text style={visualProfilo.text1}>{global.Lusername}</Text>
    //...
    }


    class FindUser extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            }
        }

        findUser(cf) {
            let params = {};
            params = {
              "Person.FiscalCode": cf
            };
            //... query to DB
              .then(response => {
                let utente = response.docs[0];
                console.log("name: ", user.Person.FirstName)
    global.Fusername = user.Person.FirstName
global.Fusername = user.Person.LastName
```

The global scope in React Native is variable global. Such as global.foo = foo, then you can use global.foo anywhere.

A good practice to define global variable is to use a js file. For example global.js

```
global.foo = foo;
global.bar = bar;
```

Then, to make sure it is executed when project initialized. For example, import the file in index.js:

```
import './global.js'
// other code
```

Now, you can use the global variable anywhere, and don't need to import global.js in each file. Try not to modify them!

Comment: From my ignorance about React Native I would like to ask you if it is a good practice to use global variables, Especially because the values ​​of FirstName and LastName are always different depending on the user who logs in

Comment: I have tried to use global Variables but they are not displayed in the View

Comment: If you are using api ( token base authentication) then you have to use global variable. Sometimes it help very help to use but difficult to maintain. Use componentDidmount method to call your data instead of other class. If you do not understand, I may help you with example

Comment: Yes I'm using API, but when I tried to show the global variable in the View They are not shown